# How to solve $2^x < x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do you solve :

$$2^x < x^2$$

My math years are behind me, so I can't wrap my head around how to continue after this step :

$$2^x - x^2 < 0$$

I think there's a trick since it's a 0 comparison inequality, but since the 2 parts have different powers, I'm not so sure...

Comment: There is no trick here. I suggest that you start by drawing the two graphs on the same set of axes. That might suggest an argument.

Comment: $\ln$ both sides.

Comment: But it is slightly tricky if you allow $x$ to be any real value. There are three values of $x$ where they are equal.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN But $2^x=x^2$ for $x=4$.

Comment: @almagest you are right.

Comment: @almagest maybe $2 <x<4$?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Or $x<-0.766665$

Comment: One can also study the function $\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 2^x - x^2$. This may involve differentiating twice.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I take it that it is the only solution if $x > 0$, is that right?

Comment: @Thrax I think it Is.

Comment: I just used the website `desmos.com` to draw the graph of $f(x)=2^x−x^2$. It seems to corroborate the 2 solutions : $2<x<4$ and $x<−0.766665$

Comment: Taking square roots gives the equivalent inequality $2^{x/2}\lt|x|$.  Drawing the two graphs $y=2^{x/2}$ and $y=|x|$ makes it easy to see there are three points of intersection: one with $x$ negative and two with $x$ positive (namely $x=2$ and $4$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x):=2^x-x^2$ has zeros at $x=2$ and $x=4$. Furthermore from $f(0)=1$ and $f(-1)=-{1\over2}$ it follows that there is a zero $\xi\in\ ]{-1},0[\ $ where $f$ changes sign. On the other hand, one computes
$$f''(x)=(\log2)^2 \cdot 2^x-2\ .$$
Since $\log2\doteq0.693$ it follows that $f''$ is monotonically increasing from negative to positive values; hence $f''$ has exactly one zero. Therefore by Rolle's theorem $f'$ has at most two zeros, hence $f$ has at most three zeros. These three zeros have already been identified; furthermore one easily verifies that $f'(2)\ne0$, $f'(4)\ne0$. This shows that $f$ changes sign at each of its zeros, and as $f$ is certainly $>0$ for large $x$ we can say that $f$ is negative for $2<x<4$ and for $x<\xi\doteq-{23\over30}$.